# BigData On Cloud ( Azure )

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, cloud, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I have already implemented production bigdata solutions mainly on premises using Hadoop and NoSQL products but never on Cloud.

Today I need to turn into the cloud, hence i'm wandering what are the known (production and not only POCs) implementations of BigData on Cloud (mainly azure) :

1. Full PaaS Solution : EMR/HDINSIGHT + S3/AzureBlob(or Azure Datalake) + Kenesis/Azure Event Hub
2. Full IaaS Distributions(CDH,HDP) : Cloudera or Hortonworks On IaaS + Kafka On IaaS
3. Hybrid PaaS + IaaS : Cold Data on S3/AzureBlob, Warm+Hot Data and commutation on IaaS Hadoop, AD as PaaS + Azure Event Hub on PaaS

Best regards

Comment: This list will always be expanding, and tomorrow the next "best" will be around, invalidating any answer you get, so do you have a specific question you're trying to ask about this architecture or these tools?

Comment: I'm agree, and I think we can expand with the evolution / maturity of technologies. my question is to know what are the best practices of bigdata on cloud today.

Comment: It depends on how much you want to manage yourself. Hybrid cloud only adds headaches for Hadoop compared to Microservices that can go anywhere. EMR & Qubole & Databricks are more "up-to-date" with cloud tech than HDP/CDH, I would say. The problem in BIg Data is "data gravity". Outside of that, you seem to care about streaming and IOT, so you could look at Confluent Cloud, and Kafka Connect because Azure/Kenesis are far more expensive for large volumes of data. Kafka Connect can write to HDFS / S3 / Azure Blobs if you need something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what have been said up, I've found many Production implementation on the Cloud using both full PAAS & IAAS solutions, one of the more mature was the Netflix one based on S3 & EMR.